# Flutter Firebase Plugin Issues: Incompatibility issues

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, flutter, android-gradle-plugin

Am getting the fololowing errors after I added firebase plugins to my flutter project:
ProcessException: Process "C:\projects\ecommerce\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* Where:
Build file 'C:\projects\ecommerce\android\app\build.gradle' line: 24
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
>   Minimum supported Gradle version is 5.4.1. Current version is 4.10.2. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the
>      distributionUrl in C:\projects\ecommerce\android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-5.4.1-all.zip.

Here's my android\app\build.gradle.

```
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.ecommerce"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Here's my android\build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.71'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
    }


}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}


//      ====SUBPROJECT DEPENDENCIES START HERE
    subprojects {
        project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
    project.configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.core'
                    && !details.requested.name.contains('androidx') ) {
                details.useVersion "1.0.1"
            }
        }
    }
  }
//ENDS HERE

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

The version of gradle in C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle:
Is 5.1.1.
The version of gradle in my android\build.gradle,
dependencies:

````
dependencies {

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
    }```

I dont know if there's any conflict between 
```classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2' ```
with:
```classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2'```

Please help
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the links that I used in a recent presentation. They contained the necessary versions of everything as of 3 weeks ago. Give them a try.

Firebase auth:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/41492#issuecomment-536112970 
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27254#issuecomment-477474444

Cloud Firestore:

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex#mdex-gradle

Answer (score 1):

So, after combing through the whole of internet for two days, I finally solved by changing the 
`classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'`
to,
`classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'`

Also, upgrading my gradle dependency in the android/build.gradle file:
from:

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'`

To:

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'`

Will help

You can refer to this post in case of same issue:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/38163#issuecomment-520429066